# SQL-injection через User-Agent

Tags: mysql, sql, безопасность, header

Согласно этому [отчёту](https://hackerone.com/reports/297478), можно выполнить SQL injection через User-Agent. Хотелось бы понять, как это работает, и каким образом обезопаситься от подобного рода атак?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User-Agent сверяется с базой данных командой вроде вот такой:

```
cursor.execute("""
    SELECT * 
    FROM log 
    WHERE user_agent = '{}'
""".format(user_agent))
```

Имеем User-Agent:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.87'XOR(if(now()=sysdate(),sleep(5*5),0))OR'
```

При этом получаем SQL команду:

```
SELECT * 
FROM log 
WHERE user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0...'XOR(if(now()=sysdate(),sleep(5*5),0))OR''
```

Профит.

Рабочий пример на [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/28d9b89/1)

Обезопаситься можно использованием параметрических запросов:

```
cursor.execute("""
    SELECT * 
    FROM log 
    WHERE user_agent = ?
""", user_agent)
```

Примеры кода - на Python